# How to load package's internal function in global environment

Tags: r

I have a package whose internal functions I want to load in the global environment. The only way I can think of is to do it manually, i.e.

```
f <- packageName:::someInternalFunction
```

For all internal functions. I'm guessing there's an easier way to do it, but how? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
library(pacman)

pack.name <- "qdap"

hidden <- setdiff(p_funs(pack.name, TRUE), p_funs(pack.name))

invisible(lapply(hidden, function(x) {

    a <- strtrim(x, 1) == "%" 
    b <- substring(x, nchar(x)) == "%"

    if (a && b) {
        x2 <- paste0("`", x, "`")
    } else {
        x2 <- x
    }

    assign(x, eval(parse(text=paste0(pack.name, ":::", x2))), 
        envir = .GlobalEnv)
}))
```

Comment: Wow, so there really isn't an import or shadowing-import in base R?

Comment: Thank you, this worked! Although like Clayton I'm a bit surprised that this is so hard to do in R...

Comment: Functions are not exported because the maintainer of the package did not include them in their "API", so to say. Why is it surprising or disappointing that doing something that the author of the original code has implicitly discouraged (i.e., using these non-exported functions outside of the package itself) is hard and hacky?

Comment: @fabians Well said.  I think that puts it into perspective.

Comment: Whoever downvoted after I agreed with @fabians (not hard to figure out who you are), this seems childish to down vote an answer that is correct because I don't happen to subscribe to your philosophy.

Comment: what is `p_funs` ? I get an error  `could not find function "p_funs" `

Comment: @d.putto Sorry that's from the **pacman** package.  Info got deleted in a previous edit.

Comment: Thx for the suggestion but, I had to modify the code as p_funs seem to work like the library function  hidden <- setdiff(p_funs(qdap, TRUE), p_funs(qdap))

Answer (score 8):

Use package `pacman` as an example:

```
attach(loadNamespace("pacman"), name = "pacman_all")
```

Now all its unexported functions are available. You can see the attached "pacman_all" with `search()`.

To revert, run `detach("pacman_all")`.

Answer (score 2):

1. download the tar.gz  with the source code for the package from CRAN and extract
2. rename to "mypackage" (e.g.) in the DESCRIPTION
3. modify its NAMESPACE to export all that you need
4. `install.package(<path to mypackage>, type="source", repos=NULL)`
5. `library("mypackage")`

You of course realize that relying on somebody else's internal functions is very dangerous as the behavior of these functions is liable to change without warning (that's one reason they're internal). installing your own modified version of the package goes some way towards reducing that danger as it gives you more control over the code you're calling.