# How to access functions from a list in assign?

Tags: r, environment, assign

Assume I defined

```
methods <- list(hurz.default = function (vehicles, mission) {
    vehicles_r <- vehicles
    return(vehicles_r)}, 
  hurz.a = function (vehicles, mission) {
    vehicles_r <- vehicles[1, ]
    return(vehicles_r)})
```

now, this is working

```
i <- 1
assign(names(methods[i]), methods[[i]])
```

but this does not:

```
lapply(c(1:length(methods)), function(i) {
        assign(names(methods[i]), methods[[i]])
})
```

I could not find the answer using [Hadley](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/environments.html).
Any thoughts?

(The idea came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22363552/5784831) but I guess this is something else.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can specify the `env`

```
lapply(seq_along(methods), function(i) {
       assign(names(methods)[i], methods[[i]], env = .GlobalEnv)
 })   


hurz.default
#function (vehicles, mission) {
#    vehicles_r <- vehicles
#    return(vehicles_r)}

hurz.a
#function (vehicles, mission) {
#    vehicles_r <- vehicles[1, ]
#    return(vehicles_r)}
```

With a `list`, another option is `list2env`

```
list2env(methods, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Ok, that's it. In my case (I use it in a package) `envir = parent.env(environment())` seems also to work. Does that look reasonable to you? At first I thought `envir = parent.env()` has to work, but this does not...

Comment: @Christoph It looks okay,